# Include .NET2.0 SP2 in bootstrapper

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I need to author an installer for a program that requires .NET Framework 2.0 SP2.

Since I didn't found a bootstrapper for .NET20SP2, I want to install a newer .NET framework assuming that it already includes the required version. I found the bootstrapper in 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A`
and chose the .NET 3.5 bootstrapper.

When I installed the bootstrapper it included .NET35 but surprisingly not .NET20SP2. You can find in the registry:

```
[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727]
    "SP"=dword:00000001
```

The condition in my WiX 3.5 installer checks this value:

```
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 2.0 SP2. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR (NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL and NOT NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL > "#1")]]>
</Condition>
```

Of course, this causes the installation to fail. How can I generate a bootstrapper that installs the required Framework version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the [.NET2 SP2 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=1639) and then [author your own bootstrapper package for it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730839%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Warning: in my experience, the slightest mistake in your XML will result in the package being silently ignored by the generatebootstrapper task without any indication as to why. I recommend you start from an existing package and gradually modify it until it does what you want.

There are other ways of generating bootstrappers like the [Burn engine](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_bundle_intro.htm) in wix 3.6, which I hope to use in the future.